# Xamarin C# Android <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I'm working on an android app, and i've stumbled upon an error i can't get passed. All of my research is pointing me to believe i'm missing some xml element, but i don't know what, so was hoping someone with more expertise could point it out.

Error in visual studio i'm getting is

```
Unhandled Exception:

Android.Views.InflateException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>
```

The error is coming from my roundbutton.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
  <solid android:color="#536878" />
  <corners android:bottomRightRadius="25dp"
      android:bottomLeftRadius="25dp"
      android:topRightRadius="25dp"
      android:topLeftRadius="25dp"/>
</shape>
```

and i'm calling that code from my main activity xml, and that snipped calling the above is:

```
<ImageButton
    android:src="@mipmap/baseline_settings_white_36"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/settingsButton_zone2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0.0dp"
    android:background = "@mipmap/roundbutton"/>
```

So, does anyone see what i have left off in my round button xml? If i remove `android:background="@mipmap/roundbutton"` then i no longer get the error and my app runs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you seeing that timeout when running without the debugger, or only when debugging? If that only happens when debugging, what happens when you're *not* debugging - is there anything in the log?

Comment: I haven't tried without debugging, I can try that, but I will need to debug my app so would like that to work.

Comment: Yes, you definitely need to debug - but if debugging only fails in one particular situation, then it's not nearly so much of a problem.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I eventually found the issue.

I was ultimately going to just do a workaround and instead of using the xml file to make by buttons round, I was going to programmatically make them round in C#. This worked, but then I ended up figuring out why the xml file wasn't working.

Turns out, I had put the file in the mipmap/anydpi-v26 folder. My emulator was trying to read from it's mipmap/xhdpi folder, and since it didn't exist in there i was getting the timeout. The solution was to move the file out of the mipmap folders and into a folder structure that wasn't going to change per device screen size.

Hopefully this can help someone else out down the road.